# Nodes having highest and lowest connections across unique node properties in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two types of nodes in a graph DB. One type is `Testplan` and the other is `Tag`.

I want to find which `Tag` nodes that have most connections across unique `Testplan.TP_MNEM` (this is a property of `Testplan` node).

To explain it in a bit more detail:

Let’s say the graph has 5 `Testplan` nodes, 3 with `TP_MNEM` as “AAA”, 1 with `TP_MNEM` as “BBB” and the other with `TP_MNEM` as “CCC”.

I want the `Tag` nodes that are connected to most types of `TP_MNEM`.
If a `Tag` Node 1 has 3 connections with `TP_MNEM` “AAA” and no connection with any other `TP_MNEM` then `Tag` Node 1 should get lower priority over `Tag` Node 2 which has 2 connections but each with unique `TP_MNEM` (“AAA” and “CCC”, for example).

Similarly I want the `Tag` nodes having highest degree but are only connected to only one type of TP_MNEM. Here Tag Node 1 will get precedence over Tag Node 2.

The code to upload a CSV is shared below:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/SRA_clean.csv" AS row

MERGE(testplan:Testplan{
TP_ID:row.TP_ID,
DB_NAME:row.DATABASE_NAME,
TP_MNEM:row.TP_MNEMONIC,
TEST_TYPE:row.TEST_TYPE,
TEST_PLAN_NAME:row.TEST_PLAN_NAME,
CREATION_DATE:row.TS_CREATION_DATE,
MODIFIED_DATE:row.TS_MODIFIED_DATE,
SQL_SERVE_UPD_DATE:row.UPDATE_DT_TM_SQL_SERV,
MYSQL_UPD_DATE:row.UPDATE_DT_TM_MY_SQL
})
FOREACH (tagName IN split(row.Keywords,",")|
MERGE (tag:Tag{name:tagName})
MERGE(testplan)-[:TAGGED]->(tag))
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please share the CSV file too.

Answer (score 0):

I may have simplified things (and/or misunderstood your questions) ... but doesn't the following query fulfill your first question ?

```
MATCH (tg:Tag)<-[:TAGGED]-(tp:Testplan)
RETURN tg.tagName, count(DISTINCT tp.TP_MNEM) AS count ORDER by count DESC;
```

And the other question ... well ... just replace **DESC** with **ASC** ...

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom